# C# webbrowser control: page opens new window but it won't work

Tags: webbrowser-control, new-window

I use a webbrowser control (in C# - latest version of visual studio and .NET) to allow me to read and write data to a specific web page. Everything is OK until I reach the point that the page attempts to open a pdf document in a new window (the page contains javascript code). 
The new window opens OK on my IE. But nothing appears when the webbrowser control opens the new window...
I've tried setting firefox as my default browser to see if it makes any difference but no good came out of it. The webbrowser control still opened IE.
I've tried catching the event of the new window and refer the url to another webbrowser control... no success again!
How can I get the pdf document? And why would the new window open but not display the pdf?